# Do Goddess Walls reappear later?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

After encountering my first Goddess Walls, I was wondering: Is it possible to use them at a later time again, or are they really just usable once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They reappear if you shut off the game and resume it.

This is necessary in order to get a heart container piece later in the game.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to turn off the game, at least I don't think so.  I've had _long_ sessions of play and was pretty sure I went to some walls multiple times within a single session.  I thought it was time based.

Comment: @JeffMercado In my experience, they don't until you save and quit, regardless of whether you shut down the system, go to the Wii main menu, or go back to the title screen.  I say this having played a 14 hour game one day, and in that entire time, the Goddess Wall directly outside the Sealed Temple didn't respawn.

Comment: I can confirm what Powerlord said. Just tried it. Simply saving and quitting resets the walls.